# Problem importing some modules in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've downloaded a panel to inject into my Angular 9 project

In the panel @core and @theme are injected which already come in downloaded folders, I access their '.module' and inject them in imports: []

I have omitted the unnecessary imports for you

```
import { CoreModule } from './modules/admin-panel/@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './modules/admin-panel/@theme/theme.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CrearCuentaComponent,
    PopoverComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    PanelDeGestionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //Importacion traducción
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    }),
    AdminPanelModule,
    //Panel robado
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),      //Here is the error
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NbChatModule.forRoot({
      messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
    }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),      //Here is the error
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers:[VarLogins]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The console error:

[image]

The routes are fine, but still do not work, what can happen? I'm sorry if I'm not more concrete but I'm very lost and not what to do

Comment: You copied your (secret?) `messageGoogleMapKey` - if this might be a problem.

Comment: What is it? it doesn't sound like anything to me. It is copied code, but the error does not jump there